# Como entrar en un input al hacer click en un td con jquery o javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un input oculto en un td y quiero que al darle click al td aparezca (esto ya lo hago) y aparezca el cursor dentro del input sin tener que volver a darle clic, para editar el input?

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu codigo para poder trabajar sobre él ?

Comment: sin codigo no somos de mucha ayuda

Comment: Simplemente usa `.focus()` en el input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo que deseas hacer, es algo similar a esto.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("table").click(function(){
    $("#idTxt").show();
    $("#idTxt").focus();
  });
});

function desaparecer(){
  $("#idTxt").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input id="idTxt" value="" type="text" hidden="" onblur="desaparecer()">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
```

Si tienes dudas me lo haces saber por comentarios!

Comment: Deberias esperar a que el autor edite su pregunta... aunque está mas o menos claro, estás dando por supuesto cosas que él tiene que añadir, asi como dando solucion cuando él no tiene una pregunta de calidad. El autor podria coger tu solucion y pirarse sin mejorar su pregunta y ni aceptar tu solucion. Un saludo

Comment: Ya tienes suficientes puntos José para saber mas o menos cómo funciona el sitio. Seguramente se te pasó, tranquilo, para la próxima tenlo en cuenta.